# Removing table subview from Superview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Hi In my app Intially i loaded a view from app delegate. Next when some button click on this root view I added this code.

```
-(IBAction)method
{
   View1 *v1=[[View1 alloc] init];
   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 320.0f, 250.0f);
   v1.view.frame=frame;

   hideView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
   hideView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   hideView.alpha =0.8;
   [hideView addSubview:v1.view];
   [self.view addSubview:hideView];
}
```

In above code View1 is another view controller and hide view is just a view in root view controller. Now totally for Root view controller two views are added. Now my question is i want to remove the two added subviews from Root view when i clicked on table cell. how to do this? And also when i added this sub views to root view scrolling also not possible to table view and saying bad access error how to resolve this?    Or any other ways to do this.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's causing the bad access errors without seeing the code where this happens. But you say that View1 is a view controller. My guess is that you set up some initialisation in `viewDidLoad` expecting it to run. But it won't. You are only initializing the class and grabbing a handle to a property (the view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set unique `tag` to any view (subview) to easily retrieve reference to them later.

In your case, for example, you can add following lines:

```
 v1.tag = 10112;
 hideView = 10113;
```

And get references to that views later you can type:

```
//view - is a root view of that subviews
View1 *v1 = [view viewWithTag:10112];
UIView *hideView = [view viewWithTag:10113];

// and now you are able to remove them:
[v1 removeFromSuperview];
[hideView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `View1` is inside `hideView`, so you can just call `[hideView removeFromSuperView];` to remove both, or just use the @Nekto solution to recognize the view you want to remove.
For the scrolling issue, it's normal that if you add a view on top of the `UITableView` you're going to loss the table's scrolling, you could look at [hitTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a) method of UIView.